# Qt signal forwarding - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a test Qt application in which everything works fine until I try to receive a signal by slot and then emit another signal (MyWidget::setValue doesn't cause an emission of MyWidget::valueChanged). What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QSlider>

class MyWidget: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void valueChanged(int value);
public slots:
    void setValue(int value){
      emit valueChanged(value);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MyWidget* win = new MyWidget;
  QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(win);
  QSpinBox* spin =new QSpinBox();
  QSlider* slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);

  spin->setMinimum(-100);
  spin->setMaximum(100);

  slider->setMinimum(-100);
  slider->setMaximum(100);

  layout->addWidget(spin);
  layout->addWidget(slider);

  QObject::connect(spin, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), slider, SLOT(setValue(int)));
  QObject::connect(slider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), win, SLOT(setValue(int)));
  QObject::connect(win, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), spin, SLOT(setValue(int)));

  win->show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: How do you know the emission doesn't happen?

Comment: If you are using Qt5 I'd recommend using the new compile-time checked `connect()` syntax rather than the old `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros that only report errors at run-time.

Comment: Aren't you creating circular dependency here?
Spin's value change will emit slider's value change.
Slider's value change will emit windows value change.
Windows value change will emit spin's value change.

Comment: @Geek: This "circular" reference is from an example and is not circular indeed.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You've created a binding loop and would overflow the stack if Qt didn't protect you from yourself by forcibly breaking the loop. As this is only a protection mechanism, its only job is to prevent a freeze and a crash. It's not supposed to make your application functional.

You have to avoid creating the loop in the first place.

You could do so e.g. by not invoking the `setValue` slot of the originating widget - recall that your `setValue` slot is called from within the `valueChanged` signal's body.